# How can I retrieve LiveAgent Settings from an org?

Tags: metadata-api, liveagent, ant, package.xml

I am using ANT to retrieve settings from a production org. I have been successful using the package file below to get LiveChatDeployment and LiveChatButton settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LiveChatDeployment</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LiveChatButton</name>
    </types>    
    <version>44.0</version>
</Package>
```

I also wish to retrieve the LiveAgentConfig and LiveAgentSettings. If I include LiveAgentConfig or LiveAgentSettings in the package.xml, the ant process throws an error along the lines of

> Entity type: 'LiveAgentSettings' is unknown

How can I retrive the agentconfig and agentsettings information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below metadata definition for [LiveAgentSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_liveagentsettings.htm). Also the wildcard character * (asterisk) will work here for [Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_settings.htm).

```
<types>
    <members>LiveAgent</members>
    <name>Settings</name>
</types>
```

For [LiveChatAgentConfig](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_livechatagentconfig.htm)

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>LiveChatAgentConfig</name>
</types>
```